# jupyter notebook + seaborn + %matplotlib notebook -> grid not visible

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter, seaborn

If I try to use in a jupyter notebook

```
%matplotlib notebook
import seaborn as sns
... 
plt.grid()
```

The the grid is not visible.
If I try the same in plain python (not jupyter notebook, without %matplotlib), the grid is fine.

Comment: I have the same problem. Couldn't future it out how to turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `plt.grid()` with no arguments toggles the grid state. Because there is a grid in the default seaborn style, you are turning it off.